# Inline Assembly GCD won't work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I've been writing a simple c++ program that uses Assembly to take the GCD of 2 numbers and output them as an example used in a tutorial I watched. I understand what it's doing, but I don't understand why it won't work.
EDIT: Should add that when it runs, it doesn't output anything at all.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
int result;
_asm
{
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, a
    mov ebx, b
looptop:
    cmp eax, 0
    je goback
    cmp eax, ebx
    jge modulo
    xchg eax, ebx
modulo:
    idiv ebx
    mov eax, edx
    jmp looptop
goback:
    mov eax, ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp

    mov result, edx
}

return result;
}

int main()
{
cout << gcd(46,90) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running it on a 32bit Windows system, any help would be appreciated. When compiling, I get 4 errors:

```
warning C4731: 'gcd' : frame pointer register 'ebp' modified by inline assembly code
warning C4731: 'gcd' : frame pointer register 'ebp' modified by inline assembly code
warning C4731: 'main' : frame pointer register 'ebp' modified by inline assembly code
warning C4731: 'main' : frame pointer register 'ebp' modified by inline assembly code
```

Comment: Those are not errors, they are warnings. But you should not mess with ebp/esp unless you know what you're doing - remove the lines dealing with those two registers. (Technically, you can add [`__declspec(naked)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs.aspx) to the function declaration instead, but don't, that's a bit more advanced.)

Comment: Oh ok, doesn't explain why it doesn't run though.

Comment: Notice that your code only reaches `goback` when division turns `edx` into `0` or `a` starts as a 0 (in this case you need to zero-initialize `edx`), meaning it will always return a 0.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will insert these or equivalent instructions for you at the beginning and end of the function:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
...
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

If you add them manually, you won't be able to access the function's parameters through `ebp`, which is why the compiler is issuing warnings.

Remove these 4 instructions.

Also, start using the debugger. Today.

Comment: Tried that, and now it chucked up an "Unhandled exception at 0x0040153b in gcdTest.exe: 0xC0000095: Integer overflow." error.

Comment: My guess is that your `edx` is not initialized before `idiv` and to initialize it you need to sign-extend `eax` into `edx` with the `cdq` instruction.

Comment: What instruction was it at which the exception occurred? What was at that address, 0x0040153b? The debugger should be able to show you the disassembly of your code. Use it.