# asm not loading parameters on stack

Tags: c, visual-c++, x86, stack, inline-assembly

I have a function that is supossed to use two integers as parameters, but whenever I access to the stack, the aren't there and I cannot use them, so I get random memory values as output. As I understand, to call a function I don't need anything else apart from what its on my code. This is inline intel asm x86

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getNum1(int a);
int main()
{
    int num1=0, num2 = 8;
    __asm {
        // push ebp
        // mov ebp,esp
        
        push num1
        push num2
        
        call getNum1

        add esp,8
        // pop ebp

        mov num1,eax
    }
    printf("%d", num1);
    return 0;
}

//this is only supossed to return the value of a, but i get random stuff
int getNum1(int a, int b)
{
    __asm {
        push ebp
        mov ebp,esp
        push ebx


        mov ebx,[ebp+12]
        mov eax,ebx


        pop ebx
        pop ebp
    }
}
```

Comment: You set up your own frame pointer inside the stack frame created by the compiler-generated code; look at it with a disassembler or on https://godbolt.org/.  If you don't want to use named args like `mov ebx, a`, don't use *inline* asm, write a separate .asm file.  Or use a `__declspec(naked)` function and include a `ret`.

Comment: The compiler already generates a prologue and epilogue for `getNum1`.  Refer to the variables by their names `a` and `b` and everything will work.  Do not attempt to build you own stack frame in inline assembly.  If you want to learn assembly, I strongly recommend you to ditch inline assembly and just write complete functions in assembly.

Comment: voting to close and DV-ting as this code will never compile. OP needs to put more effort if he wants help.

Comment: Related: [Inline Assembly GCD won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12912976) re: MSVC making its own frame pointer around your code, although that question has a different kind of problem.

Comment: @0___________: Compiles just fine on https://godbolt.org/z/7175qY3dd with x86 MSVC 19.14.  (And from the asm, looks like it should actually link, no calls to undefined names.)  It is a valid [mcve] of the bug in accessing args, due to writing code like a naked function in a non-naked function.  Perhaps you missed the fact that `call getNum1` is inside an `_asm{}` block, and thus doesn't need to come after a declaration of the function, even if this were compiled as C++ instead of C.

Comment: `int getNum1(int a);` then `int getNum1(int a, int b)`. It should not compile in C language.

Comment: @0___________ MSVC [appears to sidestep](https://godbolt.org/z/s34K1n4Ms) the standard, issuing a [C4029](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4029?view=msvc-170) warning, which states that the formal parameter list of the definition, not the declaration, is used when they differ.

Comment: @0___________: Oh, I didn't notice that mismatched prototype.  Surprised it allows garbage like that to compile.  But it does, and this is a valid [mcve].  (Of a problem that's obvious if one looks at the compiler-generated asm.)